# Please add book recommendations to the list of "don't" on the on-topic page

Tags: feature-request, on-topic

Book recommendations are off-topic on EE.SE: [Why book recommendations questions are off-topic?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6512/why-book-recommendations-questions-are-off-topic), but that is not listed in the not-about items on the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help page.

Other sites, for example Stack Overflow on their [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page, do explicitly include that item:

> 3. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Please could that be added to EE.SE's on-topic page so that users who diligently read that page don't post a question asking for a book recommendation and then get surprised when it is closed.

Comment: "users who diligently read that page" ... do such mythical creatures actually exist ? ;)

Answer (score 2):

We can do that, it will take a long time and the CM's will need to get involved. But the first question I would ask is: Is it a problem worth spending time on?

How many questions do we see on a regular basis?

There are also many other meta decisions that the community has decided on as far as on topic and we don't have info for those either.

You can also add a custom close reason if you'd like, so if there isn't a lot of questions, I'd just revert to the explanation on the meta that you posted.